# XSLT Preceding sibling issue

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I've the input xml where i ve tables and notes tags. I need to display the notes which is coming between the tables tags just like that . notes can also come in different places. I've used apply templates of note before table , so its applying all the notes before table itself .I need to display the nodes tag if its coming in between the tables just like that.

INPUT:

```
enter code here
<step>
 <note>..</note>
 <para>..</para>
 <table>
 ..
 ..
 </table>
 <note>...</note>
 <table>
   ..
   ..
 </table>
 <table>
   ..
   ..
 </table>
 <note>...</note>
 <text>...</text>
 </step>
```

## OUTPUT

```
enter code here
<fc:topic>
  <fc:subTask id="S0EC0A941" lbl="E.">
  <fc:para>..</fc:para>
  <fc:text>...</fc:text>
  <fc:note>..</fc:note>
  <fc:table>
   ..
   ..
  </fc:table>
  <fc:note>...</fc:note>
  <fc:table>
   ..
   ..
   </fc:table>
   <fc:table>
   ..
   ..
  </fc:table>
  <fc:note>...</fc:note>
  </fc:subTask>
 </fc:topic>
```

XSLT was like this :

```
<xsl:template match="step">
    <fc:topic>
        <fc:subTask>
            <xsl:if test="@id">
                <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:attribute name="lbl"><xsl:number format="A."/></xsl:attribute>         
            <xsl:apply-templates select="para"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="text"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="note"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="table"/>               
        </fc:subTask>
    </fc:topic>
</xsl:template>
```

but this is applying all the tables & notes. need to change XSLT to display the note which is coming in between table to display in the place only. if the Note is coming after the table or before the table , then it should come in that only . If its coming any where else then it can come after text.

Thanks

Comment: im new to XSLT , i m not sure how to use mode , also im trying with following-sibling::*[1] , can some one please help ?

Comment: Please show us your input XML and your desired output XML, and the output of your current XSLT code so we can see what needs to change.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide any code samples there as well  formatted code snippets, don't expect us to read code in comments.

Comment: Sorry Martin , Im new to this . I ll edit and post the new question.

Comment: I am not entirely clear on the issue, but can you try doing `<xsl:apply-templates select="note|table" />` instead of doing two separate statements?